# Incomplete method access modifier and/or non-access modifier in Android Documentation

Tags: android, code-documentation

I was studying Android's `FileProvider` API and noticed that while method [getUriForFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#geturiforfile) is static, it is not declared as `static` in the documentation:

```
Uri getUriForFile (Context context, 
            String authority, 
            File file)
```

What am I missing? Why isn't it declared as:

```
public static Uri getUriForFile (Context context, 
                          String authority, 
                          File file)
```

*Note:* It is declared as `static` in methods summary, but not in the full description section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be a bug in the JavaDocs generation for the Support Library. Framework classes show the `static` keyword where you are expecting it, as do AndroidX classes.

I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128751211) to try to get this repaired.